# Can .net micro framework project upgrade to .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-micro-framework

I am a web developer. But I have taken on a legacy project (about embedded hardware) which is written in C# with .net micro framework. My boss wants me to upgrade this project to .net core 3.1.

After searching on the Internet, it seems very hard to do that because the project code use so many built-in functionalities of .net micro framework.

For example:

```
Microsoft.SPOT.Time.TimeService.SetTimeZoneOffset(currentTimeZone * 2);
```

this statement calls an `extern` method, which is:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets time zone of the system. Effective immediately.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="offsetInMinutes"></param>
        [MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        public static extern void SetTimeZoneOffset(int offsetInMinutes);
```

and this `extern` method will call a C++ method.

I am filled with doubt about the possibility of upgrading .net micro framework to .net core.

Could you please give any comment or direction to make it?

---

**Edit**:
Thanks to @mtz, I followed the link and used ".NET Portability Analyzer" in Visual Studio 2019. The report says that DDLs used in the legacy project are compatible with .net core.

See below:
[image: Report from .NET Portability Analyzer]

Does it mean I can directly use these DDLs from .net micro framework?

Comment: *I am filled with doubt about the possibility of upgrading .net micro framework to .net core.* yeap, it's for different type of hardware ... AFAIK .NET Core needs at least ARM7 so it's not even working(no official distribution) for Pi Zero

Comment: first you should check if there is .net core runtime for your hardware ... link shows how to migrate from .NET Framework to .NET core not from .NET Micro Framework

Comment: @Selvin, thanks. The embarrassing situation is that this legacy project is assigned to me who is totally not aware of hardware. Leave it alone. Right now the problem is that my boss wants me to find methods or DLLs in .net core to replace these methods or DLLs. I googled for a long time,  but got no suitable result.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/

.NET Framework isn't exactly .NET Micro Framework, but that will give you an idea of the challenges.

I'd probably start by analyzing the csproj's if I were you, and try to move them to the new csproj format.

As for the code you have quoted, it's interop code and is not specific to the .NET Micro Framework, you can likely re-use that when retargeting to .NET Core 3. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2004/november/net-matters-threadpoolpriority-and-methodimplattribute)

Comment: Thanks for reply and link. About the last paragraph, I am wondering that whether it will work cross-platform, e.g. Linux?

Comment: Yes, interop .NET code is crossplatform friendly. See https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/

Comment: Not sure what to make of it. Just try to compile for netstandard2.0 and see what happens.